# Change the sitemap.xml size limit in magento 1.x.x

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sitemaps, crawler

It seems that Magento 1.x.x. generated sitemap.xml is limited to 10MB.

**Is there any way to change the limit?**

I do know that I'll need to split the generated sitemap into smaller chunks after that to satisfy google.

It just seems weird to me that there is no functionality for changing the sitemap size, or generated multiple small ones.

I suppose i could go to a online crawler/generator but they are usually very slow and not that effective/clean.